# SELECT the total count of page likes I have in common with other users

Tags: mysql

I want to `SELECT` the total count of **page likes I have in common with each other user** in the database.

When I'm trying this statement ...

```
SELECT
    l.item_id,
    l.uid,
    COUNT(l.item_id)
FROM
    pages_likes l
WHERE
    l.uid IN (NOT NULL, 544)
GROUP BY
   l.uid
```

... it only outputs one single record of my own total count of page likes and my user id. In this example my user id is `544`.

So I only get one record back instead of multiple records of users like I expected which should show different user id's (named `uid`) and different total counts of likes.

So my `WHERE`-condition is obviously the wrong one to go with and I would be grateful for an advise what other possibities I have to solve this issue.

Table `page_likes` structure:
`id`, `item_id`, `uid`, `date`

Comment: `l.uid IN (NOT NULL, 544)` makes no sense. `NOT NULL` is not a specific value that you can compare with.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? @GurwinderSingh I explained that I need all page likes I have in common with other users, but I don't know how to write the SELECT-statement that I include my own user id and also tell that the other user id has to be not blank. That's why I used NOT NULL.

Comment: What do you mean by "likes I have in common with all other users"? Isn't that the number of items that all users like?

Comment: @Barmar: For example there is page_id `1` + `2` I liked and `user1` likes that too, I would have 2 common likes with him in total. So I just need that total count to sort my user list by common total likes with.

Comment: Oh, you mean **each** other user, not **all** other users.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Then I'll get multiple records but I don't know what exactly is counted, because it isn't the number of counts I have in common with the user id. I can check that by visiting the specific user id. For instance I get a count result of 12 then but only have 2 common page likes with this user id.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, sorry, not my mother language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    l1.uid,
    COUNT(*) AS common_likes
FROM
    page_likes AS l1
JOIN page_likes AS l2 ON l1.item_id = l2.item_id
WHERE
    l1.uid != 544
AND l2.uid = 544
GROUP BY l1.uid
ORDER BY
    common_likes DESC
```

This joins subsets of the `page_likes` table with itself. One subset is everything liked by other users, the other is your likes. Then it counts the number of items in the pair with each other user.

Comment: With this statement I get just one single record of an user id with a `common_likes` count of nearly 1000. But when I visit the profile of this user, I only have 4 common likes with him to check if this is true. Also there are much more users I have common likes with.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I think this solution is clever joining the same table but there's something need to be changed. It seems that I get the **total count of likes** of the specific user instead of **common likes**. Also you have a typo right after your `JOIN` (`AS ll2` instead of `AS l2`).

Comment: The `ON` condition restricts it to common likes. Without the join we would get all the user's likes.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with some sample data?